# Foursquare Redirect uri mismatch on native Android OAuth login

Tags: android, foursquare

I am trying to implement Foursquare Native OAuth on my Android app. I have followed the foursquare-oauth-library sample and have succesfully generated an access_token for the user.

However, following Foursquare's recommendation of my App's Secret not being stored anywhere in the app and instead performing a server side auth code/access_token exchange I am doing the call on my server but get a redirect_uri_mismatch error everytime I do it this way.

I am getting the auth code as specified in the sample app:

```
AuthCodeResponse codeResponse = FoursquareOAuth.getAuthCodeFromResult(resultCode, data);
```

Afterwards, I send that auth code from my Android app to my rails server. I assume the access_token should be obtained following Step 3 of https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#code but I get the redirect_uri_mismatch response.

I am using Nestful on my rails server to send Foursquare my request for the access_token:

```
response = Nestful.post 'https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token',
        client_id: ENV_CONFIG['foursquare_client_id'],
        client_secret: ENV_CONFIG['foursquare_client_secret'],
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: ENV_CONFIG['redirect_uri'],
        code: params[:code]
@token = response['access_token']
```

The response is:

```
{"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch"}
```

I have already double checked the app's configuration on Foursquare, where I have also set my generated Android Hash Key, and even tried providing that as a redirect_uri parameter to generate the acess token, but to no avail.

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the given code checks upon the redirect_uri provided originally. Since one wasn't specified in the first place, no redirect_uri param should be passed to the code/access_token exchange call.